# Display checked in the table according id value in the array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have a problem displaying checked in the table according to id value in the array if I have to click the `Show checked if id values are 1 and 5` button. For example, I want to display checked in the table if id values are 1 and 5.

But I using below sample javascript coding cannot show the selected checked in the table followed by the id value:

`Javascript`

```html
function show_value() {
  var selected_value = "1,5";
  var checkbox_state = []
  var id_value = []
  //use each loop
  $("[name=checkbox_val]").each(function() {
    checkbox_state.push($(this).is(":checked"))
    id_value.push($(this).closest("tr").find("[name=id_value]").val()) //push value in array
    $("#checkbox_val").attr("checked", true);

  })
  var id_value_true = id_value.toString();
  
  
  if(jQuery.inArray(selected_value, id_value_true) !== -1){
      $("#checkbox_val").attr("checked", true);   
  }else{
      $("#checkbox_val").attr("checked", false);    
  }
  
  console.log("checkbox -- " + checkbox_state.toString() + " ID VALUE --" + id_value.toString())

}
```

Below is my whole sample coding:

```js
function show_value() {
  var selected_value = "1,5";
  var checkbox_state = []
  var id_value = []
  //use each loop
  $("[name=checkbox_val]").each(function() {
    checkbox_state.push($(this).is(":checked"))
    id_value.push($(this).closest("tr").find("[name=id_value]").val()) //push value in array
    $("#checkbox_val").attr("checked", true);

  })
  var id_value_true = id_value.toString();
  
  
  if(jQuery.inArray(selected_value, id_value_true) !== -1){
      $("#checkbox_val").attr("checked", true);   
  }else{
      $("#checkbox_val").attr("checked", false);    
  }
  
  console.log("checkbox -- " + checkbox_state.toString() + " ID VALUE --" + id_value.toString())

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Checkbox</th>
    <th>ID Value</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val" value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="id_value" name="id_value" value="1"/></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val"  value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="id_value" name="id_value" value="2"/></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val"  value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="id_value" name="id_value" value="3"/></td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val"  value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="id_value" name="id_value" value="4"/></td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val"  value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="id_value" name="id_value" value="5"/></td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_val" name="checkbox_val" value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="id_value" name="id_value" value="6"/></td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table></br>
<button type="button" id="updateBtn_5" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="show_value()">Show checked if id values are 1 and 5</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, I want the expected result like below the picture:

[image: output1]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be syntax errors in your `html`. Firstly, correct the `tag` </br> to `<br>` there is no `/` in `<br>`. Secondly, you have multiple elements with same `id` attribute. You may consider renaming them dynamically by suffixing with a number. For example, id="checkbox_val1", id="checkbox_val2", id="checkbox_val3", and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue you have is that you are repeating the same `id` in multiple elements in the DOM which is invalid. `id` attributes *must* be unique.

To achieve your goal you can split the `selected_values` string in to an array and use it to `filter()` the existing `id_value` elements to retrieve only those who have a matching value. From there you can traverse the DOM to find the related checkbox and set its `checked` property to true. Try this:

```js
$('#updateBtn_5').on('click', () => {
  var selected_values = "1,5".split(',');
  
  $('input[name="id_value"]')
    .filter((i, el) => selected_values.indexOf(el.value) != -1)
    .closest('tr').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Checkbox</th>
    <th>ID Value</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id_value" value="1" /></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id_value" value="2" /></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id_value" value="3" /></td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id_value" value="4" /></td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id_value" value="5" /></td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_val" value="0">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id_value" value="6" /></td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<button type="button" id="updateBtn_5" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Show checked if id values are 1 and 5</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can include `function show_value()` in the javascript? Because in my real situation got using AJAX pass data

Comment: In that case use a delegated event handler. Inline event handlers bound using `onclick` should be avoided, which is why I removed it.

Comment: Ok. Using a delegated event handler does not affect my use of AJAX, right?

Comment: That's right, delegated handlers are perfect for dynamic content created using AJAX.